How Can I update to g++ version 14.0 or higher in windows?
I am trying to run a project locally that requires g++ make tools for build. It needs g++ 14 version or higher. I am on Windows. Can someone guide me through the installation of a higher version of g++?
I tried following one tutorial available https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw but it is still 13.2 version.

I think you missed the pacman -Syuu step. I am doing that now on my msys2 from a MSYS2  terminal I have inside  Windows Terminal.

Where is this step mentioned in the tutorial? I can't find it

It's not in the VSCode documentation but here: https://www.msys2.org/docs/updating/

Can you tell me your version of g++? I am still getting same version after that step

It's still updating. There were 444 packages to update on my msys2. I question if you really need g++14? Are you using c++23 or possibly c++26 features? You tagged the question for c++14 which any msys2 release should support.

I am using c++26 features. I selected the wrong tag.

For me it's still showing: gcc version 13.3.0 (GCC) I thought I had seen a question or two this week where someone had 14. I am unsure how to get that.

looks like some of it has been updated https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-gcc but not all the packages https://packages.msys2.org/base/gcc
